# How to pre_populate model columns in admin using its foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

how can I prepopulate model column in django admin using model's foreign key(any column of foreign key model), I have found that in official docs, they say prepopulated_fields doesn't work with a foreign key, any other do you know any other approaches?